# Сайт не индексируется в Google

Tags: seo, индексация, google-search

Столкнулся с неизвестностью - создал поддомен, понемногу дописываю на него форум, а в поисковой выдаче не появляется.

Доступ к сайту вроде нормальный, домен стоит уже больше 3 месяцев, на него есть внешние ссылки, даже вручную добавлял его на индексацию в инструментах веб-мастера Гугла, дал ссылку на карту сайта, ошибок не обнаружилось.

По запросу site:d.prineside.com нет ни одной страницы (домену больше трех месяцев), в то время как недавно (пару недель) созданный сайт mta-w.com с его единственной страницей уже есть в индексе (site:mta-w.com).

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: http://d.prineside.com/sitemap.xml
```

Мета в заголовке:

```
<meta name="Robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Гугол там сообщения оставляет по сайтам.  
Вам какое-нибудь оставил?

Comment: @I_CaR, рекомендаций нет. В инструментах Гугла по графикам идет индексация, вполне нормально выглядят графики загрузок страниц в день, но в самой выдаче Гугла нет ни одной страницы

Answer (score 1):

mta-w.com - домен 2-го уровня, а d.prineside.com - домен третьего уровня... В этом вся проблема... Побольше ссылок (штук 10-20) на d.prineside.com и он появится в поиске через недельку-другую, максимум месяц!

Comment: Я уже говорил - ему больше 3 месяцев, на него есть ссылки, в том числе на сайтах с доменом 2-го уровня. Сначала у этого сайта был домен delirium.prineside.com, который существовал даже меньше, чем 2 месяца, и на него почти не было ссылок, тем не менее его Google проиндексировал. Очевидно, что здесь не просто ждать надо, здесь проблема в другом.

Answer (score 0):

А вы доработали файл robots.txt? Не удивлюсь, если сайт вообще не индексируется.